# How to parse time in this format 2019-07-30 16:45:00.9 C#

Tags: c#, datetime, parsing

I receive date string in this format :

2019-07-30 16:45:00.9

2019-08-01 09:00:00.0

2019-08-01 11:30:00.0

The code I am using below works fine before 12 pm. After that it doesn't parse correctly

```
string dateString, format;  
      DateTime result;
      CultureInfo provider = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;


dateString= "2019-07-30 16:45:00.9";
format = "yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss.f";
try {
         result = DateTime.ParseExact(dateString, format, provider);
         Console.WriteLine("{0} converts to {1}.", dateString, result.ToString());  }
      catch (FormatException) {
         Console.WriteLine("{0} is not in the correct format.", dateString);
      }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your current format is for 12 hrs clock, which is why anything after 12 pm fails to parse.

Use capital `HH` in your format for 24hrs times.

```
format = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.f";
```